# Consuming web services with Liferay

Tags: web-services, liferay, portlet

i have little experience with Liferay, builded a couple of sites with static content and built-in portlets and now I need to build my own portlet which consume a web service defined by a WSDL. Is there a "standard" way to do it? For standard I mean a way to reuse the libraries that already use Liferay for web services. I know that it uses Axis and I don't want to include another library in my portlet. Does Liferay have an interface for web services clients? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liferay provides a [web service client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.1.0%20GA1/liferay-portal-client-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.zip/download) for calling Liferay services themselves through SOAP. But this is probably not what you're looking for.

Liferay has no standard for calling external web services. We've done this before in several projects and we had to write the customizations ourselves. Also, you cannot really reuse the Axis libraries Liferay uses, because they are on a different classpath. So unless you write your web service client inside an Ext plugin, you have to manually add WS dependencies yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: +1 for the link to the Liferay web services client. Saved me potentially hours of work trying to roll my own from the Axis 1.4-generated WSDL's that Liferay automatically generates.  Bonus: This client jar is even available in Maven.

Comment: I like to consume .NET SOAP web services in my liferay dxp. can anyone guide me on how to consume it ? I am using gradle build tool. please provide me the sample code.